# JavaFX deployed as embedded in webbrowser

Tags: deployment, javafx-8

I developed a JavaFX 8 application as a desktop app. 
Then created a self-signed certificate, packed the app into JAR, signed this JAR with the certificate, created a JNLP and HTML file for my application. Copied these files into the appropriate Tomcat folder. 
Then tried to load the HTML page from localhost:8080/...
A splash screen appeared, then a progress bar and I saw my application, but it was not completely displayed. I used a BorderPane as layout and its top side was displayed, but not the center and bottom sides. By the way the center side was filled with TabPane. Every tab I implemented as a separate class. Can it be the problem?

Comment: Read the tag-descriptions before adding!

Comment: I assume it runs ok in your IDE. Does it run from the jar file you create (i.e. from the command line / terminal, if you do `java -jar myfile.jar`, does it work correctly)? (As an aside, in the "answer" below, I think you are conversing with a spam bot...)

Comment: Yes, it runs ok in my IDE. I tried to run it from the command line and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: How are you creating the JNLP and HTML? Are you using the JavaFX packaging tools?

Comment: I created them using Ant tasks, but I signed the JARs manually (with jarsigner).

Comment: You are right! The problem was in .html. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm actually not convinced I was much help there, but glad you figured it out.